# How to set read unread flag in php message system

Tags: php

I'm developing a Facebook-type messaging system in PHP. I have a `user_message` table which contains `sender_id`, `receiver_id`, `message`, and `flag` as *read/unread*. After inserting a value in this table, I make it as unread and when the user clicks on the message notification, then the status will be updated as *read*.

It is working fine for single user. While sending message to multiple users though, I am storing `receiver_id` as comma separated values in the table. My problem is that how to set flag for multiple receivers? if I'm sending one message to 3 users, for example, then how can I set the *read* flag? Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While sending message to multiple users though, I am storing receiver_id as comma separated values in the table.

Don't misuse a string column to represent multiple values. It's impossible to index a column structured that way in most DBMSes, so you won't be able to search it efficiently. This is particularly significant for a "message recipient" structure, as it means that it's impossible to efficiently search for all messages received by a specific user. This would make many common operations like checking for new messages sent to a user, or viewing a user's mailbox, extremely slow on a large site.

Instead, if you want to have a single representation of a message sent to many people, rather than a separate message for each one, model this using two tables, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE message (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    sender_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    message TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE message_recipient (
    message_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    recipient_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id, recipient_id)
);
```

With such a table structure, you can place a "read" flag on the `message_recipient` object, so that each recipient of a given message has a separate read status.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd done the same thing wht u'd mention. i've created two tables and now everything is working fine. I really Appreciate your help. Thanks very much. I'd accepted this as answer also.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a juntion table between `message` table and `receiver` table. For example **MessageRead** table. it has `id`(auto increment) `message_id` and `receiver_id`. If user with id=10 read the message with id=5, you need to execute this query:

```
INSERT INTO MessageRead(message_id, receiver_id) VALUES(5, 10)
```

For getting number of users that read the message with id=5, you can execute this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MessageRead WHERE message_id = 5
```

And, for checking if user with id = 10 read the message with id = 5, execute this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MessageRead WHERE message_id = 5 AND receiver_id = 10
```

If the result of this query is 1, it means the user has read the message, otherwise he has not read the message.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can add field with name "users_reads" and put in it IDs of users, who read message, separating by comma. How to check if user reads message:

```
if (in_array($userId, explode(',', $row['users_reads']))) { ... }
```

2) You can add new table 'users_reads_messages' in your database with fields:
- message_id
- reader_id

3) you can make a copy of message with another reciever_id, I mean you put single user id in this field, for other users you make a copy of this message in your table.

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Thanks ver much for quick response and i think i got my solution. I'll try with above solution and i m accepting it as answer. Thanks very much again bro.